# Product Attributes not updating. Screen just appears to refresh on save

Tags: admin, product-attribute

I am trying to update a custom attribute field.  When I add the content and hit save   no changes are made and the screen only to appears to refresh.

Comment: Is this attribute in a custom module that was recently installed? Try clearing your cache

Comment: It may happen because of query caches also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Magento custom model won't allow DB table changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751694/magento-custom-model-wont-allow-db-table-changes)

> Clear you cache. The Zend classes Magento uses to read database
>   columns will cache that information (such that it's not necessary to
>   do a DESCRIBE for each model load/save). Clear out your cache and
>   Magento should see the new columns, and values will start persisting
>   to the database.

Comment: This was a request that came in from an older customer.  They are on 1.6.  Cache was disabled. I still flushed, refreshed, and turned cache on.

Comment: Was there any db table changes made? Is this issue on a core magento functionality?

Comment: The only thing I've seen is that the customer duplicated a product and is making the changes to publish a new one.  When I duplicated the product they did I get the same errors.  However when I duplicated another one, no errors. I recommended scrapping the product and starting fresh. Its working.